# Test Vaadin Textfield with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, vaadin

I created a save button and a textfield in Vaadin. The save button state (enabled/disabled) is binded to the textfields input with a ValueChangeListener. When the textfield is empty the save button should be disabled, otherwise it should be enabled.

It works fine in a livetest, but Selenium is not setting the text properly. I can see Selenium setting the text input, but the save button is not getting enabled.

```
new Actions(getDriver()).moveToElement(wrappedElement)
    .click()
    .sendKeys(SELECT_ALL_SHORTCUT, Keys.DELETE)
    .sendKeys(wrappedElement, text)
    .sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
    .moveByOffset(1, 1)
    .perform();
```

I tried lots of different ways to set the text, i can see in the browser that the text is set, but the save buttons state doesnt change always, at least it works sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Focus event on your textField is not triggered so value is not properly set in that moment. Easiest way to trigger it is to perform some other action before checking your save button, for example, you could perform `click()` on some other text field so your textField will loose focus and text will be properly stored.
Another option is some javascript function which will trigger this event, but this is more complicated solution and depends on your page specific implementation.

Comment: I also thought that the focus is the problem thats why i told Selenium to tab out the textfield after it sets the text. After I set an input to the textfield that is binded to the save button I set some inputs to other textfields, so this is not the solution.

Comment: Ok, but instead of setting input in other fields try to just perform click() action. TAB action won't help too in these kind of situations. That's it, I'm out of other solutions, sorry if it's not helping. :)